# Press gesture recognizer causing app to hit exception breakpoint

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I'm on Yosemite and the latest OS X SDK (10.10) and I'm trying to add a press gesture recognizer to a view using storyboard:

[image]

However, when I add this press gesture recognizes, my app hits a exception breakpoint on start:

[image]

It's stuck there even if I click resume button many times (with nothing at the log at all). If I disable breakpoints and hit resume, my app works, though the gesture recognizer is not working. If I remove the gesture recognizer, my app doesn't hit an exception breakpoint so I assume the gesture recognizer is the cause. There's nothing fancy about it, it's just a regular press gesture recognizer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a delegate associated with the gesture recognizer in the nib?  If so, make sure that the connection is valid (if you see a "!" there on the connections inspector, you'll have found your problem).

Comment: From recent past experience I found that gesture recognizer seems to have some bugs (particularly with OS X storyboards), and some of the gestures don't even seem to work depending on the segue used; I would recommend filing a bug report.